# Name for submodule killed by a right ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, terminology

Let $\mathfrak a$ be a right ideal in a ring $R$. The set $N=\{m\in M: \mathfrak am=\mathfrak 0\}$ is a submodule of the left $R-$module $M$:

If $m,n\in N$, $a\in \mathfrak a$, then $a(m-n) = am-an = 0$ combined with $a0=0$ shows that $M$ is a subgroup, and if $r\in R$, $a(rm)=a'm=0$ shows that $N$ is a submodule.

I figured this submodule would have a name somewhat akin to Ann(M) for the left ideal in $R$ killed by $M$, but I haven't been able to find anything on it.

Comment: You could call it the $a$-torsion submodule.

Answer (score 1):

I really feel like I have seen this called "the annihilator of $\mathfrak{a}$ in $M$" and denoted $Ann_M(\mathfrak{a})$, but I have been unable to find a source quickly.

That would be a reasonable name in any case.